# Earth visited by an enormous creature

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

I'm trying to remember the author and title of a short story about the Earth in the far future which is visited by an enormous creature (maybe like a continent sized salamander) which devastates the world but is worshipped by the people. It returns periodically with earth-shattering consequences. Any ideas?

Comment: 1960's at the very latest.

Comment: NSFW the Perry Bible Fellowship comics has a strip "Earth Disorder" where an enormous creature visits Earth and causes much destruction: http://pbfcomics.com/96

Comment: This question does not have an accepted answer and should **be reopened**.

Answer (score 10):

I believe that might be Brian Aldiss's "Heresies of the Huge God". The story is from the journals of a priest of the Huge God, a giant, many-legged, lizard shaped creature which arrives on Earth (it's described as looking like a gecko on a globe) and causes massive destruction, stomping mountains flat, disrupting the weather and so on. The people worship it, but heretics pray for it to leave. It does at the end of the story, but as it jumps off its weight knocks Earth out of orbit and the people start praying for it to return.

Originally published in 1966, I read it collected in "Man In His Time" ISBN: 0-02-030225-8 [978-0-02-030225-4] and here's a list of other places it was collected: https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?52433. You can check it out here and see if it's the same story, although it is terribly formatted it's the only link I could find to the text: http://docs4.chomikuj.pl/2271392519,PL,0,0,Brian-W-Aldiss---Heresies-of-the-Huge-God-(txt).txt

Comment: +1, this is almost certainly it, and one of my favourite Aldiss shorts.